# What is the mechanism behind the spectral property change in voltage sensitive dyes?

Tags: electromagnetism, molecular-dynamics, density-functional-theory

As far as I understand the change in spectral properties of [voltage sensitive dyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage-sensitive_dye) is partially derived from the [Stark Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark_effect). However, even if this is the underlying physical phenomena, it is still unclear how the effect takes places.

In other words, what are the intermediate steps and most importantly, how do the bonds and electron system change in this? I understand this is a complicated question, as the [molecular dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_dynamics) is a hard nut to crack.